# AWS S3 Connection in druid

Tags: amazon-s3, druid

I have set up a clustered Druid with the configuration as mentioned in the Druid documentation

https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/cluster.html

I am using AWS S3 for deep storage. Following is the snippet of my common configuration file

```
druid.extensions.loadList=["druid-datasketches", "mysql-metadata-storage", "druid-s3-extensions", "druid-orc-extensions", "druid-lookups-cached-global"]
# For S3:
druid.storage.type=s3
druid.storage.bucket=bucket-name
druid.storage.baseKey=druid/segments
#druid.storage.disableAcl=true
druid.storage.sse.type=s3
#druid.s3.accessKey=...
#druid.s3.secretKey=...

# For S3:
druid.indexer.logs.type=s3
druid.indexer.logs.s3Bucket=bucket-name
druid.indexer.logs.s3Prefix=druid/stage/indexing-logs
```

While running any ingestion task I am getting Access denied error

```
Java.io.IOException: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: ; S3 Extended Request ID: ), S3 Extended Request ID: 
    at org.apache.druid.storage.s3.S3DataSegmentPusher.push(S3DataSegmentPusher.java:103) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.druid.segment.realtime.appenderator.AppenderatorImpl.lambda$mergeAndPush$4(AppenderatorImpl.java:791) ~[druid-server-0.19.0.jar:0.19.0]
    at org.apache.druid.java.util.common.RetryUtils.retry(RetryUtils.java:87) ~[druid-core-0.19.0.jar:0.19.0]
    at org.apache.druid.java.util.common.RetryUtils.retry(RetryUtils.java:115) ~[druid-core-0.19.0.jar:0.19.0]
    at org.apache.druid.java.util.common.RetryUtils.retry(RetryUtils.java:105) ~[druid-core-0.19.0.jar:0.19.0]
```

I am using s3 for two purposes

1. read data from s3 and ingest it. This connection is working fine and data is being from s3 location
2. for deep storage. I am getting error over here.

I am using Profile information authentication method to provide s3 credential. So I already have configured aws cli with appropriate credentials. Also, s3 data is encrypted by AES256 so i have added **druid.storage.sse.type=s3** in config file.

Can someone help me out here as I am not able to debug the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have set the correct permissions in IAM? Otherwise try setting the permissions full open for S3 (temporarily). If that works, you know for sure that it has to do something with the IAM permissions (or not).

Comment: Yes, I have the correct permissions. I was missing some config, I changed it a liitle.  I uncommented #druid.storage.disableAcl=true and keep other configurations intact, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You asked how to approach debugging this.  Normally I would:

1. Ssh onto the ec2 instance and run `aws sts get-caller-identity`.  This will tell you what principal your requests are sent from.  Then, I would confirm that principal has the S3 access that is expected.
2. I would confirm that I can write to the bucket in your configuration.

```
druid.storage.type=s3
druid.storage.bucket=<bucket-name>
druid.storage.baseKey=druid/segments
```

3. I would try some of the other auth methods such as exporting the keys into the environment mentioned in the third option since that is a simple test.  Then I would run step 1 again to confirm my principal reflects those keys. And then I would try running your code again.
   [image]